# Async: What practices in large classes?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Is it a good idea to make **large classes** fully Async compatible or should another method be used?

Example for understanding:

**AsyncValidateUserInput.cs**

```
public async Task<TaskStateHelper> CheckSiteIsReachable()
public async Task<TaskStateHelper> VerifyCertificate()
public async Task<TaskStateHelper> TestAccount()
{
    #DoStuff
    await exchangeAccount.FetchAccountInformation
    #DoStuff
    await exchangeAccount.GetAccountBalance
    #DoStuff
}
```

GetAccountBalance is based on the AccountManager class:

**AccountManager.cs**

```
public async Task<decimal> GetAccountBalance()
{
    #DoStuff
    await FooAPI.GetAccountBalanceAsync()
}
```

**FooAPI.cs**

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, decimal>> GetAccountBalanceAsync()
{
    var queryResult = await QueryPrivateAsync("Balance");
    #DoStuff
}

private async Task<Stream> QueryPrivateAsync(string method, Dictionary<string, string> param = null)
{
    #DoStuff
    await postStream.WriteAsync(postData);
    #DoStuff
    await ReadFromStreamAsync(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    #DoStuff
}
```

Another way would be to simply create a task.

```
result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(exchangeAccount.GetAccountBalance);
```

Do I use Async rule-compliant?

Thank you for your time

Comment: If `GetAccountBalance` accessing external resource, manually create tasks with `Task.Run` si definitely wrong approach, which will simple waste of resources(threads)

Comment: Why you doubt about amount of async methods? Did you face some issues?

Comment: More interesting is what lead you to ask this question.

Comment: The size of the class doesn't really matter. What does matter is the begin and the end of your call chain.  The WriteAsync() says Yes, but it's only one half. Using StartNew() is a totally different approach to async or concurrency.

Comment: @Fabio No problems have occurred so far. I haven't seen it in an example.

Comment: @Evk The question with 'class size' was more related to performance and code guidelines.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorry, I didn't put it well enough. large class = a class that uses all your functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is generally a good idea to make anything Async that should be, no matter the size. This article might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then I did it right :)
I already know the article.